# SSO in ms access 2010

Tags: active-directory, ldap, single-sign-on, ms-access-2010

Is it possible to do SSO in ms access 2010 db application. If so how would I achieve this?

So far I have ldap authentication on login form, but I would like bypass this and automatically move on to next screen. The following is what I have so far

```
Function CheckUser(username As String, passwd As String, Level As Integer) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo LDAP_Error

    Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2

    Dim LDAPPath As String
    LDAPPath = "LDAP://akutan.usa.domain.com/OU=Sites;DC=domain;DC=com"

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    conn.Properties("User ID") = "domain\" & username
    conn.Properties("Password") = "" & passwd
    conn.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True
    'conn.Properties("ADSI Flag") = 3
    conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
    cmd.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM '" & LDAPPath & "' WHERE " & "objectCategory='user'"

    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    rs.Close
    conn.Close

    CheckUser = True
    [TempVars]![CurrentUser] = username
    Call LogUser([TempVars]![CurrentUser], "Logon")
    Exit Function

LDAP_Error:

    If Err.Number = -2147217911 Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect PeopleSoftID or Password!", vbExclamation, "LDAP Authentication"
    Else
        MsgBox "Error : " & Err.Description & " " & Err.Number, vbExclamation, "LDAP Authentication"
    End If

    CheckUser = False
    conn.Close      
End Function
```

Comment: http://www.accesssecurityblog.com/post/2011/02/05/Securing-Access-databases-using-Active-Directory.aspx   maybe this applies...

Comment: This shows security permission which I shall also try to implement but not exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

I use 'Access Data Projects' in order to make a single login for all of my tables / sprocs.